# Opencv : How to increase the letters size without increasing image size?

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I would like to increase the letters size in the image contains letter distributed in multiple lines and keep their coordinates the same also remove the lines in between the letters .
For Example
:

[image]

I have applied **Morphological Transformations**. It helps but not enough for character recognition using **tesseract OCR** the problem in this image in letter **4**

I have applied `erode` and `cv2.MORPH_CLOSE`

```
kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(img,kernel,iterations = 1)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(erosion, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

and I get this output 
:
[image]

**Edited**
The Input Image

- https://ibb.co/i2FdkT
- https://ibb.co/igiQX8

The Complete code i used

```
import cv2
import numpy as np



img = cv2.imread('total_2.png',0)



edges = cv2.Canny(img,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
minLineLength=100
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=1,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=80)

a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    x = lines[i][0][0] - lines [i][0][2]
    y = lines[i][0][1] - lines [i][0][3]
    if x!= 0 and abs(y/x) <1:
        cv2.line(img, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

se = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE , (4,3))
gray = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, se)
img = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, None, 65, 5, 21)
img = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
k1 = np.zeros((3, 3), np.uint8)

img = cv2.erode(img, k1, iterations = 1)

ret,img = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,0)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.cv2.MORPH_RECT,(3,3))
kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)


#dilation = cv2.dilate(img,element,iterations = 1)
erosion = cv2.erode(img,element,iterations = 1)



kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
#opening = cv2.morphologyEx(erosion, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, element)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(erosion, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, element)
```

Another approach with `cv2.findContours`

```
# threshold the gray image to binarize, and negate it

_,binary = cv2.threshold(image, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

if flag :

    binary = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)



# find external contours of all shapes

_,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)



# create a mask for floodfill function, see documentation

h,w= image.shape

mask = np.zeros((h+2,w+2), np.uint8)



# determine which contour belongs to a square or rectangle

for cnt in contours:

    poly = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.05*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)

    if len(poly) == 4:

        # if the contour has 4 vertices then floodfill that contour with black color

        cnt = np.vstack(cnt).squeeze()

        _,binary,_,_ = cv2.floodFill(binary, mask, tuple(cnt[0]), 0)

# convert image back to original color

if flag:

    binary = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)
```

The problem with `cv2.findContours` is that I have other images I apply the same preprocessing technique over them but they are unboxed and this approach destroys some letters.

For Example this Image 
:

[image]

My ideal solution would be increasing the letter sizes and also make the letter more clear

Comment: You already have toned down your input image and converted it to a binary image, it seems to be a bit difficult from this point to recover the lost information accurately, can you share the original image and the code using which you generated these binary images ?

Comment: Edited the question by adding input image and code that generate this binary image

Comment: Have you thought about finding contours (cv2.findcontours) and filter your contours out with convexity criterion or size criterion (to eliminate squares) and then resizing the contour (multiply the list of points) and finally drawing them on a new image mask.

Comment: My problem with this approach is that I have other images with no rounded boxes so if I apply the same code to a non-boxed it removes the characters and destroys the image. I have added i used for this purpose may small modification needed